# Regex domain validation

Tags: regex

The following code

```
/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*‌​)?$/ix
```

validates all types of domains.

I would like to validate only one domain or subdomain (for example `.cu.cc` or `.co.cc`).

Comment: The `{1}` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to the end of your domain regex:

```
(?<=\.cu\.cc)$
```

It's a positive look-behind

Answer (score 0):

The final `\.[a-z]{2,6}` is what matches a top-level domain. Change it to whatever specific TLD you want to match.